# UIActivityIndicator issues -- sometimes it doesn't stop

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an activity indicator that is working fine. Most of the time. But sometimes it just keeps going. The code is pretty spread about, so I'll have to explain.

I'm doing a calculation. Sometimes it only needs updating, so it's fast. Sometimes it's lengthy, and may have to get new data from a server.  When the calculation takes some time, the activity indicator works. When it's fast, though, the activity indicator will start, but not stop. Is there a minimum time for the animation? Has anyone else run into this?

I'll try writing something to gate the startAnimation based on the last time the calculation was done. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: OK. it' solved. Logging (as suggested) did show up that there was second call to `startAnimating`, leading to a race condition: sometimes the calculation was long enough that both calls arrived before the stop. I've now eliminated the second call and it's working!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you call `endAnimation` before `startAnimation` or not at all. These are the most common causes for such problems...

Did you try `NSLog` when these two methods are called?

Comment: They're called in the correct order. I had logged near the statements, but apparently not near enough. When I got closer, I found the second call (see updated question).

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you call `stopAnimating` from the main thread? Changes in the UI have to be made on the main thread. Otherwise you will experience nothing at all, strange behavior or delays.

Put something like that NSLog before you call stopAnimating to make sure it is called at all and from the main thread.

```
NSLog(@"main thread? %@", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"YES" : @"NO!");
```

Doing UI updates from another thread is often the reason for unexpected results, particularly for UIActivityIndicatorViews because they are usually used with threads.

Comment: The calculation is on a separate thread, but I'm handling a number if UI changes at once, and the others are fine. This NSLog statement is nice to know, though.

Answer (score 1):

For these situations I like to build a sort of reference counted activity indicator. Basically every time you do something on the network, you increment the network activity count. Then when it's done you decrement. If it ever hits 0, you stop it. If it's above 0, you start it.

Comment: Nice idea. I ll try that next time.

Comment: Exactly. I use the same method for network indicator in status bar.